# Replace content in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, batch-processing, xslt

I need to edit some XML files, and would like to create a script to do this.  My experience with XML is almost non-existent, which is why I'm asking your help.

The XML below contains 2 transport orders: one that has a positive **value** element, and one that has a negative value.  What I would like to do is, for every transport order that contains negative **value**:

- replace the **pickup_task**'s addressid with the **delivery task**'s addressid, and vice versa
- replace the pickup task's **taskwindow** (from_instant and till_instant) with the values of the delivery task.

Is it possible to make a VB script or batch or something that could replace these for a file with more than 200 transport_orders?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<misu version="2010">
    <transport_orders>
        <transport_order>
            <id>NOCCO/12-006798_1</id>
            <order_number>NOCCO/12-006798_1</order_number>
            <order_date>2012-03-30</order_date>
            <contactId>C04396</contactId>
            <productId>0103-01101025</productId>
            <sum>3135.51</sum>
            <currency_code></currency_code>
            <reference>NOCCO/12-006798</reference>
            <amounts>
                <amount>
                    <unit_code>kg</unit_code>
                    <value>324.00</value>
                </amount>
            </amounts>
            <pickup_task>
                <addressid>BUCU</addressid>
                <task_window>
                    <from_instant>2012-04-20T18:26:43</from_instant>
                    <till_instant>2012-04-20T18:26:43</till_instant>
                </task_window>
            </pickup_task>
            <delivery_task>
                <addressid>C04396_1</addressid>
                <task_window>
                    <from_instant>2012-04-23T00:00:00</from_instant>
                    <till_instant>2012-04-24T00:00:00</till_instant>
                </task_window>
            </delivery_task>
        </transport_order>
        <transport_order>
            <id>NOCCO/12-007016_2</id>
            <order_number>NOCCO/12-007016_2</order_number>
            <order_date>2012-04-02</order_date>
            <contactId>C01137</contactId>
            <productId>0604-08L15000</productId>
            <sum>495.00</sum>
            <currency_code></currency_code>
            <reference>NOCCO/12-007016</reference>
            <amounts>
                <amount>
                    <unit_code>m2</unit_code>
                    <value>-5.00</value>
                </amount>
            </amounts>
            <pickup_task>
                <addressid>SFGH</addressid>
                <task_window>
                    <from_instant>2012-04-20T18:26:43</from_instant>
                    <till_instant>2012-04-20T18:26:43</till_instant>
                </task_window>
            </pickup_task>
            <delivery_task>
                <addressid>C01137_1</addressid>
                <task_window>
                    <from_instant>2012-04-23T00:00:00</from_instant>
                    <till_instant>2012-04-24T00:00:00</till_instant>
                </task_window>
            </delivery_task>
        </transport_order>
    </transport_orders>
</misu>
```

Comment: What platforms/languages are you open to ...?

Comment: Well the most relevant one is visual basic, i usualy write code only with help from here and there.

Comment: Would that be VB.NET or VB Script?  (Powershell?)  This would be fairly straightforward in .NET, but I guess that's not what you want ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go ... this should accomplish part 1.  I'll leave part 2 up to you (I'm not used to VB).  As you can see I named the XML file "data.xml".

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xdoc As XDocument
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "../../data/data.xml"
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename)
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = xdoc.Root.Element("transport_orders")
    For Each element In xe.Elements("transport_order")
        Dim val As Integer
        val = element.Element("amounts").Element("amount").Element("value").Value
        If (val < 0) Then
            Console.WriteLine(val)
            Dim puelement As XElement
            Dim delelement As XElement
            Dim putask As String
            puelement = element.Element("pickup_task").Element("addressid")
            delelement = element.Element("delivery_task").Element("addressid")
            putask = delelement.Value
            delelement.Value = puelement.Value
            puelement.Value = putask
        End If
    Next
    xdoc.Save(filename)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Back with feed, the thing is working gorceously, as i allready said my knowledge is limited and i always try to understand what a code does and try to reproduce to fit my needs so here is what i did for the  my second question, i know is quite lame but it shall do the job, please confirm it

```
puelement2  = element.Element("pickup_task").Element("task_window").Element("from_instant")
delelement2 = element.Element("delivery_task").Element("task_window").Element("from_instant")
putask2 = delelement2.Value
delelement2.Value = puelement2.Value
puelement2.Value = putask2

puelement3 = element.Element("pickup_task").Element("task_window").Element("till_instant")
delelement3 = element.Element("delivery_task").Element("task_window").Element("till_instant")
putask3 = delelement3.Value
delelement3.Value = puelement3.Value
puelement3.Value = putask3
```

Thanks. Realy helpfull.

Comment: This is not a real answer. You should update the question if you want to clarify things or ask about additional details. Or ask a new question.